# Do I have to collect each bit of belief manually?

Tags: godus

Once you've got your believers to settle in their own hut, periodically a pink bubble will form above the home. This seems to vary in size depending on the size of the hut the believer(s) are living in, and I'm assuming that the size of the bubble will influence the amount of belief you gain by popping it.

[image]

However, as you can see, the amount of bubbles that appear grows rapidly as your number of believers increases.

Additionally, if I do not click on the bubbles immediately, am I essentially wasting belief or does it accumulate in each bubble for each believer until I get around to clicking it?

Do I have to collect each bit of belief manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There is no way to automate the belief collection; no matter what, you have to keep clicking.

Just like it's predecessor, Populous, Godus mandates clicking, and lots of it.

So click on, brave god! Click forever!

Comment: SO MUCH CLICKING

Comment: In the mobile version, there's a shrine which helps a lot with this, you only have to click the shrine. Don't know how it's about in the desktop version, but afaik the answer is NO not YES.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, yes. You must click. You must click a lot in order to collect belief. You can also hear a groovy Mozart concerto in the process. This applies to the primitive age of development.

Later, once you've developed some, when you can put down a statue and create a settlement, belief will gather at that statue. Then you can click a bit less often to collect a lot of belief at once. It will still involve clicking and a lot of it, but with greater yields than before.

Comment: Larger settlements take longer to generate belief, which is less clicking along with the settlements.  You'll also find that there is a tipping point to where you will have tons of belief and don't need to click the bubbles at all really.