# What actions generate belief?

Tags: godus

From what I can gather, belief is expended whenever you use one of your abilities, for now I'm pretty much limited to reshaping the world under my control but it looks like there are plenty of others things that will open up to me later on (totems, etc).

So far, I've established that poking at trees and rocks will give me belief. Oh, and [popping bubbles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132302/52800).

[image]

What other actions generate belief?

Comment: I voted to close because Godus is still very much in development, this answer can be very different come 1.0 release. O'course with the advent of Steam early access, this may need to be discussed in meta.

Comment: @Elpezmuerto - Minecraft was in development for well over 2 years, and that didn't stop us from answering questions about it. If it's (publicly) available to play, we can answer it.

Comment: @Robotnik I wouldn't even say that Minecraft is *out* of development now. ;)

Comment: True, I just feel squishy about it. But that is for meta

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - No, neither would I, but they made the distinction between beta and release at some point :P

Comment: @Elpezmuerto I'm pretty sure it's well established that a publicly-available game is on topic, no matter how it might change in the future. (After all, the developer might get hit by a bus tomorrow and all development halt forever. Topicality isn't determined by things we can only determine by seeing into the future.)

Comment: @Elpezmuerto - There is also the case of Spiral Knights, a game well out of development, that was recently patched to remove a significant mechanic of the game. We handled it by [closing/deleting](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7458/should-i-vote-to-close-questions-if-they-are-outdated) questions that could not exist due to the changed mechanics, (We did this because the game was unplayable without being on the latest patch), as well as updating answers on the related but relatively unaffected questions.

Comment: @robotnik's suggestion sounds like a much better solution than closing this question.

Comment: I bring your attention to the [meta discussion that makes this question on topic on this site](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5539/52800).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get belief from:

- Breaking rocks
- Breaking trees
- popping belief bubbles
- cards (there are belief cards)

Breaking wolves takes belief, but doesn't appear to grant belief.  I'm also not out of the starting age, there could be different ways in later ages.

**UPDATE**

This was to version 1.2...
There is now version 1.3 coming out soon, [read the patch notes](https://22cans.zendesk.com/entries/25337932-When-is-V1-3-coming-out) and I believe many of these answers to Godus questions will be altered.